# Nuxt App: Azure webapp deploy using zip failing with 504.0 GatewayTimeout

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, nuxt.js, azure-appservice

I have a Nuxt 2 app which I am trying to deploy to azure app services. I ran this:

```
az webapp deploy --resource-group <resource_group> --name <app> --type zip --src-path releases.zip --timeout 900000 --verbose

This command is in preview and under development. Reference and support levels: https://aka.ms/CLI_refstatus
Initiating deployment
Deploying from local path: releases.zip
Deployment API: https://<app>.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/publish?type=zip
An error occured during deployment. Status Code: 504, Details: 504.0 GatewayTimeout
Command ran in 295.202 seconds (init: 0.090, invoke: 295.112)
```

I have a timeout flag set, but it's still timing out in 295 seconds.

The size of my releases.zip is ~117MB. It includes the whole project (after running `yarn install` and `yarn build`)

I have these configs (along with others)

1. HOST set to 0.0.0.0
2. WEBSITE_ENABLE_SYNC_UPDATE_SITE to true

Do you guys know if I am missing something ?

Thanks !

Comment: Did you checked some of those answers? https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A8816585+azure

Comment: Update `WEBSITE_ENABLE_SYNC_UPDATE_SITE` to false and check once